# No consigo insertar en el PHP para que funcione el captcha

Tags: php, captcha

Mi formulario:

```html
<form name="ajax-form" id="ajax-form" action="mail-it2.php" method="post">
  <div class="eight columns" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 100px over 0.5s after 0.1s">
    <label for="name"> 
       <span class="error" id="err-name">su nombre</span>
      </label>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre: *" />
  </div>

  <div class="eight columns" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 100px over 0.5s after 0.1s">
    <label for="email"> 
       <span class="error" id="err-email">su e-mail</span>
       <span class="error" id="err-emailvld">e-mail is not a valid format</span>
      </label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail: " />
  </div>

  <div class="eight columns" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 100px over 0.5s after 0.1s">
    <label for="marca"> 
       <span class="error" id="err-name">marca/modelo</span>
      </label>
    <input name="marca" id="marca" type="text" placeholder="modelo/marca: *" />
  </div>
  <div class="eight columns" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 100px over 0.5s after 0.1s">
    <label for="averia"> 
       <span class="error" id="err-name">Avería</span>
      </label>
    <input name="averia" id="averia" type="text" placeholder="avería (pantlla rota/no enciende/etc...: *" />
  </div>
  <div class="sixteen columns" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 100px over 0.5s after 0.1s">
    <label for="message"></label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="cuéntanos brevemente..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="sixteen columns" data-scroll-reveal="enter bottom move 100px over 0.5s after 0.1s">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MI KEY DE GOOGLE ESTA PUESTA"></div>

    <div id="button-con"><button class="send_message" id="send"><span data-hover="submit">ENVIAR</span></button></div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="error text-align-center" id="err-form">There was a problem validating the form please check!</div>
<div class="error text-align-center" id="err-timedout">The connection to the server timed out!</div>
<div class="error" id="err-state"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="ajaxsuccess">Successfully sent!!</div>
```

y ahora en el php TENGO:

```
<?php


/* Code by jose rebollo - www.joserebollo.com */
/* Editable entries are bellow */


$send_to = "info@joserebollo.com";
$send_subject = "Ajax form ";




/*Be careful when editing below this line */


$f_name = cleanupentries($_POST["name"]);
$f_email = cleanupentries($_POST["email"]);
$f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);
$f_marca = cleanupentries($_POST["marca"]);
$f_averia = cleanupentries($_POST["averia"]);
$f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);
$recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function cleanupentries($entry) {
    $entry = trim($entry);
    $entry = stripslashes($entry);
    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);

    return $entry;
}

$message = "Este email fue recibido el dia " . date('d-m-Y') . 
"\n\nName: " . $f_name . 
"\n\nE-Mail: " . $f_email . 
"\n\nmarca: " . $f_marca .
"\n\naveria: " . $f_averia .
"\n\nMessage: \n" . $f_message . 
"\n\n\nTechnical Details:\n" . $from_ip . "\n" . $from_browser;

$send_subject .= " - {$f_name}";

$headers = "From: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if (!$f_email) {
    echo "no email";
    exit;
}else if (!$f_name){
    echo "no name";
    exit;
}else{
    if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "invalid email";
        exit;
    }

}



?>
```

¿Qué código tendría que poner para que el captcha funcionara?

Comment: Hola José, no se ve bien tu código. Editalo por favor. Y tambien dinos que captcha estás usando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme. estoy loco ya! jeejej no consigo  ponerlo captcha de google v2

Comment: Debes editar tu codigo aquí, de todos modos ya edité mi respuesta con lo que necesitas.

Comment: lo se lo he visto, pero sigo sin saber donde localizarl el evento y que modificar, he tocado tantas cosas ya que no se donde esta los menssajes de exito o error, echame otro cable porfavor y con esto zanjo todos mis problemas y podre VIVIR ejejejee

Comment: Ya he colocado lo que debes cambiar, espero que por fin ya quede bien.

Comment: siento ser pesado pero ... ahora al pulsar enviar aunque le des  con los campos rellenos y captcha relleno me dice siempre que el captcha no es valido, no quiero hacer espam pero si quieres te dejo la web para que veas que siempre sale el captcha no es valido

Comment: Tienes que debuguear que es lo que te está respondiendo el server. Usa la tecla f12 para mostrar la consola. checa este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOQDrGrd9H8
Si sabes lo que te responde el servidor, vas a saber que está pasando.

Comment: a tanto no llego memoadian. imposible !  no se donde puede estar el bug 
voy a restarurar el contac.js  porque no voy a encontrar eso en la vida

Answer (score 2):

**EDICION 2**

lo que tienes que editar en tu código js es esto

la funcion success de AJAX nos devuelve la respuesta del servidor

```
success: function(data) {//el parámetro data contiene la respuesta
    // en este caso con el ejemplo que te di en el php
    // va a regresar 'el captcha no es válido' si no se clicka
    // esto se debe regresar en formato json, pero no quiero complicarte más
    if (data == 'el captcha no es válido') {//si no es válido
        // hacemos un alert que puedes cambiar, por lo que quieras,
        // esto es solo de muestra
        alert(data);
    } else {
        //si no muestra ese error, se oculta aquí debes jugar con más resultados.
        $('#ajax-form').slideUp('slow');
        $('#ajaxsuccess').slideDown('slow');
    }
}
```

**EDICIÓN**

**Al parecer el problema que tienes es en realidad de Javascript cuando tu das click en enviar formulario este hace una petición AJAX y sea cual sea la respuesta, desencadenas un evento para mostrar el div con el mensaje de exito.
Para evitar esto debes procesar la respuesta del servidor en tu código javascript. Dependiendo del mensaje que te devuelva debes mostrar un mensaje de éxito o error.**

---

Para poder validar el recaptcha en google debes hacer una petición, en este caso varias fuentes indican que lo mejor es file_get_contents

validas si el captcha está bien y si lo haces sigues con el recorrido a tu siguiente código.

Ya he probado todo lo que has peusto y debe funcionar así.

```
<?php
$captcha = false;

//guardas el captcha enviado por post
$recaptcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

//url para verificar con google
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

//tus secret API y la variable de recaptcha
$data = array(
    'secret' => '6LcMm4kUAAAAABHQzqH4iMCC_0ZlVN2djEFO_EuB',
    'response' => $recaptcha
);

//hacemos una peticion con file get contents para verificar si es válido
$options = array(
    'http' => array (
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method' => 'POST', 'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$captcha_success = json_decode($verify);
if ($captcha_success->success) {
    $captcha = true;
}

if ($captcha) {
    /* Code by jose rebollo - www.joserebollo.com */
    /* Editable entries are bellow */
    function cleanupentries($entry) {
        $entry = trim($entry);
        $entry = stripslashes($entry);
        $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);

        return $entry;
    }

    $send_to = "info@joserebollo.com";
    $send_subject = "Ajax form ";

    /*Be careful when editing below this line */
    $f_name = cleanupentries($_POST["name"]);
    $f_email = cleanupentries($_POST["email"]);
    $f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);
    $f_marca = cleanupentries($_POST["marca"]);
    $f_averia = cleanupentries($_POST["averia"]);
    $f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);

    $from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $message = "Este email fue recibido el dia " . date('d-m-Y') . 
    "\n\nName: " . $f_name . 
    "\n\nE-Mail: " . $f_email . 
    "\n\nmarca: " . $f_marca .
    "\n\naveria: " . $f_averia .
    "\n\nMessage: \n" . $f_message . 
    "\n\n\nTechnical Details:\n" . $from_ip . "\n" . $from_browser;

    $send_subject .= " - {$f_name}";

    $headers = "From: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    if (!$f_email) {
        echo "no email";
        exit;
    }else if (!$f_name){
        echo "no name";
        exit;
    }else{
        if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
            echo "true";
        }else{
            echo "invalid email";
            exit;
        }

    }
} else{
    echo "el captcha no es válido";
}
?>
```

Comment: si hasta ahi es donde tengo yo hecho y me sale el captcha el problema lo tengo ene el php porfavor. es el php el que no lo tengo bien. Porque no se queu tengo que poner en el php mi del formulario

Comment: Ok ahi edite el post.

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!!!!!! de corazón:
el codigo ahora si funciona bien pero con una connotacion: si rellenos los campos y pulso enviar sin pulsar en el captcha
me sale un mensaje en un div mio con"Successfully sent!!"
pero el correo en realidad no llega.
y si relleno los campos y activo en captcha el correo si llega es un gran AVANCE para mi despues de 3 dias buscando informacion:
podrias decirme como prohibir el boton enviar si la persona no acpeto el captcha?
y ya con esto de estaria todo conforme.
deberia de salir algo como: no se puede enviar email sino acecptas el captcha?
podrias ?
mucha

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/135581)

Comment: buenas memoadian
he editado todo el codigo. pero cuando lo subo y lo pruebo puedo mandar emial sin pasar por el captcha?
algo me sigue fallando
muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: disculpa raul. No, No es otra pregunta.. es que algo he puesto mal en el codigo sigo con el mismo tema y el mismo problema estoy esperando a memoadian para que me de soporte y ayuda.
muchas gracias raul

Comment: pero si es parte de tu pregunta lo mejor es editarla y agregar este código

Comment: Ya he editado la respuesta con todo el código.

Comment: Lo que pasa Jose, es que seguramente estás mandando el mensaje por AJAX, entonces el mensaje de enviado en inglés simplemente aparece cuando aprietas el botón enviar. Aunque no se envíe el formulario estas desencadenando el evento con Javascript y eso no tiene nada que ver con que se apruebe o no el captcha, si no con un submit, o un click en javascript.

Comment: si si lo estoy mandando con ajax lo cambio esto <div id="button-con"><button class="send_message" id="send"><span data-hover="submit">ENVIAR</span></button por imput?

Comment: Pon el código JS que usas para enviar el formulario por AJAX. Con eso te puedo dar la respuesta que estás buscando.

Comment: Lo he puesto en una edicion (jeje) aun me estoy haciendo con esto de editar jejeje

Comment: abro una nueva pregunta con ese problema? es que no lo localizo donde esta